# FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter on repeating pattern files

Tags: spring-integration

I am pulling files via FTP from a filesystem that sequentially loops through file names. For example:

```
abc.000.txt
abc.001.txt
abc.002.txt
...
abc.999.txt
```

It will then go back to abc.000.txt.

I am using FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with redis for the metadataStore. How can I get it to know to expect abc.000.txt as the next file after abc.999.txt?

My configuration:

```
@Bean
public FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter ftpPersistantFilter() {
    return new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "ftpPersistentAcceptOnce");
}

@Bean
public Expression remoteDirectory() {
    return new LiteralExpression(this.remoteDirectory);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpInboundFlow() {
    DateTime currentUtcDay = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.ftp(ftpSessionFactory())
                            .preserveTimestamp(true)
                            .remoteDirectoryExpression(remoteDirectory())
                            .filter(ftpPersistantFilter())
                            .localFilename(f -> (currentUtcDay.toString("YYYYMMdd")) + "." + f)
                            .localDirectory(new File(this.localDirectory)),
                    e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter").autoStartup(true))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("ftpInboundResultChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "expect abc.000.txt as the next file"; the filter has no knowledge of the fact that you have a sequence of files.

However, as long as the last modified file timestamp changes, the new file will pass the filter.

Comment: That probably answers my question. It takes about 2 days to cycle back to the first sequence number, so I'll let it run and see if I get the results I expect.